# will_paginate not working, returning an error of undefined method `total_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to paginate microposts. I use the following :
    <%= will_paginate @user.microposts %>
But it returns an error of :
undefined method `total_pages' for #
Please help
My controller method is as follows :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index,:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :destroy
  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
  def new
     @user = User.new
  end
  def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])  
    if params[:user].present? &&    @user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit(:name,:password,  :password_confirmation))
   flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
   sign_in @user
   redirect_to @user
   else
    render 'edit'
   end
  end


  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])  
    if params[:user].present? &&    @user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit(:name,:password, :password_confirmation))
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to @user
    else
     render 'edit'
    end
   end

  def create
    @user=  User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
    else
     render 'new'
    end
   end


   private
     def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation,   :email,:name)
     end 
   private
     def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in." 
     end
    end
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
 end
```

Comment: Can you please post your controller method.

Comment: Are you using the `.page` or `.paginate` method to load the records? will_paginate doesn't work if you just call `.all`

Comment: I am using .paginate method

Comment: I added @user = User.find(params[:id]) in the users_controller, but it yields the same error

Answer (score 0):

Here: `@microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])`.

`@user` has not defined inside `index` nor is set in any `before_filter` (if you are using Rails 4.*, `before_action` is the new syntax. `before_filter` is [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L190-L193) in Rails 5)

EDITED: and @Sukanta is right about the view

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<%= will_paginate @microposts %>
```

instead

```
<%= will_paginate @user.microposts %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]`  means that correct_user method will only work for edit and update methods. For index method to use it, you need to add index method to the list. i.e,
`before_filter :correct_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]`
And, also use before_action instead of before_filter.